# Quartz Cron Scheduled job in webapp isn't running (JBoss EAP 7.4 bootable jar)

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jboss-eap-7

I am attempting to add a cron job to my webapp. I've added the Quartz and Quartz-Jobs 2.3.2 dependencies to my pom file, added the following to web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Using the default quartz.properties file

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: JobScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO

org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true
org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 3
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class: org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames: scheduler.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound: true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval: 120
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction: false
```

and a simple Job class

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloJob.class);
        logger.info("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and the following scheduler.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
  version="1.8">

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>helloJob</name>
            <group>MYJOB_GROUP</group>
            <job-class>myapp.utils.HelloJob</job-class>
        </job>

        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>my-trigger</name>
                <group>MYTRIGGER_GROUP</group>
                <job-name>helloJob</job-name>
                <job-group>MYJOB_GROUP</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

As far as I can tell, this should output to my log every minute, and while I can see where the Scheduler is initialized and it indicates that it has started, I don't see any output from the job in my log file. What am I doing wrong?